# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "akhil"

Tags: postgresql, command-line

I have installed PostgreSQL 10.0 on my Windows 10, during the installation it asked me to enter a password for root user and I have created one. I wanted to run it over the command line and have set environment variables, but when i try to launch it by typing

```
C:\Users\akhil\Documents\Flask Examples\postsql>psql sample.sql
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "akhil"
```

I've seen some solutions to change the **pg_hba.conf** file but It couln't help me.
(update)
I've also tried to create a user id but it shows the same error

```
createuser akhil
Password:
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password   authentication failed for user "akhil"
```

Comment: The password you gave during installation is probably linked to the user postgres. But you are trying to connect as akhil (your windows username). Try specifying the user name on the command line `psql -Upostgres sample.sql` and then supply the password you used during installation.

Comment: how to login to postgres user by default ?

Comment: You could set the PGUSER environment variable `SET PGUSER=postgres` you will have to do this everytime you open a command prompt. list of possible variables https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/libpq-envars.html

Comment: Looks like you can use [`setx PGUSER postgres`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) instead of set to make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get in to your database.

```
psql postgres://username:password@ip_address/database < sample.sql
```